# Create cover flow using UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a cover flow image slide something like this :

[image]

I have to say I don't want to use others framework like [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) I need to write my own code. here is my codes but it only shows me one image per page , I was wondering how can I change my code to add `previous` and `next` image like the image ?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

  pageControl.numberOfPages = imageArray.count
        scrollView.frame = self.view.frame
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(pageControl.numberOfPages) , height: 0)
        scrollView.delegate = self

        for i in 0..<imageArray.count {

            ashvanImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 50 , height: self.view.frame.height - 200))
            ashvanImage.center = scrollView.center
            ashvanImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            ashvanImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(i).jpg")
            scrollView.addSubview(ashvanImage)
            createPageWith(images: ashvanImage, page: i)

        }
}


  func createPageWith(images:UIImageView, page:Int)  {

        let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(page), y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height))
        newView.addSubview(images)
        scrollView.addSubview(newView)
    }



    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(page)

    }
```

Comment: " have to say I don't want to use others framework like iCarousel I need to write my own code" Very commendable. But then I suggest you use UICollectionView for this. This is just the sort of thing it is good at.

Comment: Switch to an UICollectionView and enable paging.

Comment: @matt is there any possible way to create it with scrollView ?

Comment: @Mc.Lover You are displaying 57 objects on your screen. That means you will have to manually manage all the memory handling and view reuses in your scrollview. In other words, you will have to basically create a scrollView that does everything that UICollectionView does for you if you don't want to run into memory problems having 57 views/images/UIViews in memory at all time for a **single page**. I wouldn't even do it even if that is possible to do, it is not best practices and completely wrong, unless you create the entire setup and memory handler for it as I mentioned.

Comment: @Sneak  that is just an image from google :)

Comment: @Mc.Lover I see, but the problem I described still persists, unless you are showing 2-3 views. (Even then, I would not use something that have stuff in memory when not needed) This is why the UICollectionView is best practice for this stuff, it takes care of handling the memory for you when the views move in and out of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, if you don't want to use iCarousel, which has CoverFlow built in, you should use a UICollectionView. It is built for what you want.

Certainly you could do this starting from a `UIScrollView`, but it would probably take an experienced developer several weeks of full-time work to get a clean design working and debugged, and the result would look and feel a whole lot like a collection view when you were done, only not as flexible or as maintainable. Plus you'd need pretty advanced knowledge of Core Animation, which is pretty specialized and not very well documented.

### EDIT:

A Google search on "UICollectionView CoverFlow Swift" found this framework on Github:

https://github.com/sumitlni/LNICoverFlowLayout

If you're determined to do this yourself, you could at least look over that framework as a road map for what you'd need to do.

Comment: Thanks for your tips !

Answer (score 0):

You are set scrollview's width equal to the whole view, make it less like 85% or 90% or according to your requirement.

Which will solve half of your problem.

By looking at the design i think you want the view to animate.
So first, turn off scrolling for the scrollview.

Then add 2 gesture's on the scrollview, one for right swipe and another for left swipe.

Then scroll the view 1 page at a time according to the gesture and animate the view's size by changing its x position by 1 page and decreasing its size and increasing the incoming one's.
You can use the default method UIScrollView.animate too.